# Writing Stored Procedures in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: database, stored-procedures, procedure

I am trying to write a stored procedure which inserts the username and password into the database. And there is an `Identity` column which auto-increments itself. But I am not able to get the syntax correct !

Here is the code snippet:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SPRegisterUser
   @Username_V nvarchar(100),
   @Email_V nvarchar(100),
   @Password_V nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @count int;
    Declare @ReturnCode int;

    Select @count = COUNT(Username)
    from Register 
    where Username = @Username_V

    If @count > 0
    Begin
        Set ReturnCode = -1
    End
    Else 
    Begin
        Set ReturnCode = 1

        Insert into Register 
        values(@Username_V, @Email_V, @Password_V)
    END

    RETURN
```

The error generated is

> Incorrect Syntax near'='
>   Incorrect syntax near RETURN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the following line

```
RETURN
```

needs to be replaced by this

```
RETURN @ReturnCode
```

Also you're missing the final `END`

Also, variables need to start with a `@`, so change the two lines

```
SET ReturnCode ...
```

to

```
SET @ReturnCode ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be:

```
Set @ReturnCode=1
```

It is a variable declared further up.

Comment: Specific reference to the "@"